# Find word and put character in front of line

Tags: notepad++

I would like to put a semicolon (`;`) in front of a line when there is "`G383`".

Note that "`N`" and "`B`" are always followed by a random number.

For example:

```
N4919 G383 B6000 G79  ( Mill length        )
```

needs to become

```
;N4919 G383 B6000 G79  ( Mill length        )
```

How can I add the semicolon at the beginning of the lines where "`G838`" is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?\bG\d+\b`
- Replace with: `;$0`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
.*?         : 0 or more any character, not greedy
\b          : word boundary
G           : literally G
\d+         : 1 or more digits
\b          : word boundary
```

- *Check regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Replacement:**

```
;$0         : semicolon followed by the full match
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Find:     ^(.*G383)
Replace:  ;\1
```

(I.e. find everything from beginning of line up to and including 'G383' and replace it with semi-colon followed by the [first] match.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable length positive lookahead.  My Notepad warns me (when I first click Replace) that it is a "zero length match".  Just click Replace a second time and it works fine.  No capture groups, no references.

Find: `^(?=.*G383)`
Replace: `;`